# Image Upload not working in Meteor

Tags: meteor

In my meteor app I am uploading images and storing them in dropbox. It works fine when I am running the app in localhost. But as soon as I run the app after deploying it to meteor.com the upload fails to work.

This is my code in server.js

```
var createThumb = function(fileObj, readStream, writeStream) {
// Transform the image into a 10x10px thumbnail
gm(readStream, fileObj.name()).resize('10', '10').stream().pipe(writeStream);
};

var dropboxStore = new FS.Store.Dropbox("files", {
key: "",
secret: "",
token: "", // Don’t share your access token with anyone.
transformWrite: createThumb, //optional
})

Images = new FS.Collection("files", {
   stores: [dropboxStore]
});

Images.allow({
'insert': function () {
    // add custom authentication code here
    return true;
 }
});
```

Here is the link to meteor.com http://image_upload.meteor.com/.

I have tried changing dropbox to s3 but it still doesn't work. Could it be because it is hosted at meteor.com?

Looking forward for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it's because you're trying to use GraphicsMagick to resize the image in the `transformWrite` option, but meteor.com hosting servers do not have GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick installed.

https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/299

You can use the `meteor logs` command to view the logs from your hosted meteor.com application to make sure that's the issue.

**Edit**

Here's some sample code for the jQuery cropper utility:

Template HTML:

```
<input type="file" style="visibility:hidden;width:1px" accept="image/gif, image/jpeg, image/png" class="profilePhotoFile">
<input type="button" id="btnEditPhoto" value="Edit Photo" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:160px"/>

<div class="modal fade" id="cropper-modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="cropper">
          <img src="" alt="Picture">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSavePhoto">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnCancel">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Template JS:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'click #btnEditPhoto': function(event, template) {
        $('.profilePhotoFile').click();
    },
    'change .profilePhotoFile': function(event, template) {
        if (!event.target.files || event.target.files.length === 0) {
            return;
        } else {
            var $inputImage = $(event.target);
            var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var file = event.target.files[0];
            var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            $image = $('#cropper > img');

            $('#cropper-modal').modal();

            $('#cropper-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                $image.cropper({
                    aspectRatio: 1.0,
                    autoCropArea: 1.0
                }).cropper('replace', blobURL);

                $inputImage.val('');
            }).on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
                $image.cropper('destroy');
                URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL); // Revoke url
            });
        }
    },
    'click #btnSavePhoto': function(event, template) {
        $image = $('#cropper > img');

        //Change the width and height to your desired size
        var base64EncodedImage = $image.cropper('getCroppedCanvas', {width: 10, height: 10}).toDataURL('image/jpeg');

        $('#cropper-modal').modal('hide');

        var newImage = new FS.File(base64EncodedImage);

        Images.insert(newImage, function(err, fileObj) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                //do something after insert
            }
        });
    },
    'click #btnCancel': function(event, template) {
        $('#cropper-modal').modal('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes that is the issue. You are a life saver. How can I add graphics magic to meteor.com?

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like there's no way to install it on the free servers. Your other option is to use a client side library to resize/crop the images. I've used `jonblum:jquery-cropper`, which provides a lot of functionality with only a few lines of code. You can then save the image using the `FS.File` object on the client, just like you're doing now.

Comment: The best demo site for the jQuery cropper utility is http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/

Comment: Can I get a sample code on JSFiddle on how to do this? My main transformation is going to be re-sizing the images.

Comment: I added some sample code for the jQuery cropper to my original answer. This is copy/paste and massaged a little, so there may be typos, but the concept is there. I used a modal to display the cropper, because the canvas resizes after the user selects a file and I couldn't get it to stay a square on the page. After the user's done the `getCroppedCanvas` function will resize to the width/height given and return a base 64 encoded string, which can then be passed to the FS.File object constructor.